# Easyocr Python Image Size too big

Tags: python, nexus, easyocr

I have a simple problem using easyocr library in python. When I deploy my python OCR api to kubernetes It fails because of the image size of the script on Nexus Repository Manager. When I check the libraries installed by EasyOcr I found lots of libraries related to nvidia etc.
I'm using easyocr with cpu so I don't need any library related to GPU. Can I delete them somehow to reduce image size? It downloads the libraries from the requirements.txt I provided.I can't change the max image size in nexus.

Comment: What happens if you delete the libraries you think you don't need?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I couldn't find a library related to nvidia. When I tried to do as you said most of them caused error on runtime. I was thinking if there is a available easyocr library that purely downloads packages for CPU

Comment: did you find how to download only CPU related dependencies